# findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam() always returning null or empty list?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Here is my `dao` method for accessing the tuple if I execute this query from `sqldeveloper` its working fine.

```
public ClassName  getLastProcessedTupleSourceDest(Long ID,
        String srcIp, String destIp) {
    String [] param = {"ID","SRC_IP","DST_IP"};
    Object [] values = {Id,"'"+srcIp+"'","'"+destIp+"'"};
    List<ClassName> tuplesByPFChek = (List<ClassName>) (hibernateTemplate
            .findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("findTuplesWithSrcDstforCheck",param, values));
    if(!tuplesByPFChek.isEmpty() && tuplesByPFChek.get(0)!=null)
        return tuplesByPFChek.get(0);

    log.info("ali: returning null = tuplesByPFChek.isEmpty():"+tuplesByPFChek.isEmpty());
    return null;        
}
```

The above method is always printing log.info().. But if execute the query displayed in hibernate logger in sqldeveloper it is returning rows..

Where am I going wrong? Thanx

Comment: Try getting rid of single quotes in your values array, ie `Object [] values = {Id, srcIp, destIp};`

Comment: Yeah I tried that one...

Comment: Post the code of `findTuplesWithSrcDstforCheck`, and also print out the actual SQL generated by Hibernate, it should give you a clue of what's wrong.